# Escrever em um arquivo de outro site PHP

Tags: php

Olá, tenho dois sites, preciso enviar dados de um para o outro com php

Site 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Texto</label>
    <input type="text" name="texto">
    <input class="btn btn-sucess" type='submit' name='submit' value='Gravar'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site 2: (Ele receberá os dados do form e gravará no próprio arquivo porém não sei como fazer o formulário ir para o outro site)

```
<?php
$pegou = $_POST['texto'];
$fp = fopen("index.php", "a");

$txt = "\n";
fwrite($fp, $txt);
$txt = " ".$pegou."\n";
fwrite($fp, $txt);


fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="index.php">`acho que vc quer colocar a ação do form, é isso. Ou vc quer em ajax?

Comment: Sim, mas os dados do formulário está no site 1, tem que ir para o site 2, o action serve para outros sites também?

Comment: Existe uma regra de segurança para cada site, o que vc quer fazer é basicamente RestFul, utilizar uma API, de um site e publicar em outro, primeiro vc precisa ter acesso as ambas as propriedades dos sites, ou ter uma acesso CORS, e para fazer isso, só utilizando ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como disse o @LeonardoGetulio, **n** formas de fazer isso, vou dar um exemplo de como fazer isso através de ajax:

**Sua HTML no site um:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Texto</label>
    <input type="text" id="texto" name="texto">
    <button class="btn btn-sucess" id="send">Gravar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**O javascript:**

```
<script>

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //depois que o dom for lido


    function processRequest() {

        //AQUI VOCÊ RECEBE OS DADOS DO SITE DOIS
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                //sucesso, você obterá retorno de um JSON com dados 
                console.log(xhr)
             }else {
               //erro, vc obterá retorno de um JSON com erros
               console.log(xhr)
            }
        }
    }
   var button = document.getElementById('send'),
       input_text = document.querySelector('#texto'),
       actionSend = function() {

               //ENVIA PARA O SITE DOIS
                var url = 'http://www.sitedois.com.br/index.php',
                    dados = {
                       texto: input_text.value;
                    };
                 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                 if (xhr.withCredentials !== undefined) {
                   /* AQUI VOCÊ PROVAVELMENTE VAI PRECISAR 
                      VALIDAR AS CREDENCIAIS ENVIANDO NO HEADER 
                      O QUE O SITE PEDE PARA PODER LIBERAR O DADO */
                  //xhr.setRequestHeader("PARAMETROS","VALORES");
                 }
                var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

                 xhr.open("POST", url + '?rnd='+randomNum, false);
                 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dados));
                 xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
         }
          xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
          button.addEventListener("click", actionSend, false); 


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe "n" formas de se fazer isto, vou dar exemplo de 2.

1. Você redireciona seu formulário par enviar para o segundo site, os campos devem ter os mesmos ID's para o site que vai receber interpretá-los e concluir a ação. Exemplo:

   ```
   <form action="http://www.siteexemplo.com.br/pagina.php" method="POST">
   ```
2. Você envia o formulário para você mesmo, recebe os dados e envia via php/curl para outro site. Desta forma, se o site retorna algum valor de confirmação você consegue tratar/validar, principalmente se for uma API. Fica mais ou menos assim como enviar:

   ```
   $dadosParaEnviar = http_build_query($arrayDadosRecebidos);
   $url = "http://www.siteexemplo.com.br/pagina.php";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dadosParaEnviar);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if (curl_errno($ch)) {
       throw new \Exception('cURL error: '. curl_error($ch));
   }
   $resultHeader = curl_getinfo($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   ```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui adaptando os seus códigos